# rule to enforce named imports are on their own line

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I have been working on an eslint standard for our company, and one of the styles we were trying to enforce is that all named imports are on their own line. I had expected `object-curly-newline` with `ImportDeclaration` set might accomplish this, however this only appears to enforce that the objects are always on multiple lines.

So basically I want a rule in my config that allows the following import styles

```js
// Valid
import {
  x,
  y,
  z
} from './foo';

import {
  x
} from './foo';

import { x } from './foo';
```

But the rule would disallow the following named import styles.

```js
// Invalid
import { x, y, z } from './foo';

import {
  x, y, z
} from './foo';
```